# Embed SAP BO Dashboard into iframe occupying the iframe full size

Tags: html, iframe, business-objects

After embedding a SAP BO object (a dashboard) into an iframe, I've noticed that the width and height of the iframe is not the same as its content. For instance, if I set width:100% and height:100%, the content is stretched as much as an aspect ratio would allow, i.e., it does not occupy the whole iframe. If I set explicit width and heights in pixels, the behavior is the same. The dashboard occupies a certain area and above and under it are blank spaces. I want the dashboard to fill the whole iframe. Is it possible?

the iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="#{componenteM.url}" frameborder="0" style="height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute; top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px; overflow:scroll; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: none;" scrolling="no"/>
```

The url redirects to an OpenDocument link.

Comment: How are you embedding it? Can you post the HTML code you're using? Are you using an OpenDocument link or a direct reference to SWF? If the latter, have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122886/how-to-resize-a-swf-file-depending-on-screen-size).

Comment: I've edited my question. I'm embedding using an iFrame and I'm using an OpenDocument link.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do so, as you would need to change the contents of the document contained in the `iframe`, which I doubt you can. Even if you could, consider a resized flash object: you would only be able to change the size while maintaining the aspect ratio, it would never be able to change to a different aspect ratio as the content is fixed (the elements in the dashboard won't reposition themselves depending on the canvas size).